# Restrict access to people.aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to restrict access to Sharepoint people.aspx page.I have done changes in web.config people by authorization but still the user is able to access the page.Please suggest me how to restrict access to it.
The changes done to web.config file as adding location and authorization and allow access.

Comment: Here is the same question : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46193/sharepoint-people-aspx-page-is-visible-for-all-users

Answer (score 0):

remove "View Application Pages" option form permission level for the read only permission group

check this: [SharePoint People.aspx Page is Visible for All Users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46193/sharepoint-people-aspx-page-is-visible-for-all-users)